# Problem using React useState in faq accodion application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

There is a challenge on the frontend mentor website (FAQ accordion).  I have solved the challenge using React.  However, my code is not working properly.

Except for the first click on any question when page loads, I have to double-click each question to toggle it.  I suspect something wrong in my code with useState.

I created a component that renders a list of questions/answers and displays them using the `details` HTML tag. I want to solve the problem using the details tag only.

Here is my code for the component:

```
import { Fragment, useState } from "react";
import minus from "./icon-minus.svg";
import plus from "./icon-plus.svg";

const Faq = ({ questionsObj }) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState(null);
  function handleClick(id) {
    if (selectedId !== id) {
      setSelectedId(id);
    }
    if (selectedId === id) {
      setIsOpen(!isOpen);
    }
  }

  return (
    <main>
      {questionsObj.map((question, index) => (
        <Fragment key={question.id}>
          <details
            onClick={(e) => handleClick(question.id)}
            open={selectedId === question.id ? isOpen : null}
          >
            <summary>
              <span>{question.question}</span>

              <img
                src={
                  isOpen === false && selectedId === question.id
                    ? `${minus}`
                    : `${plus}`
                }
                alt=""
              />
            </summary>
            <p className="animate__animated animate__flipInX">
              {question.answer}
            </p>
          </details>
          {index !== questionsObj.length - 1 ? <hr /> : null}
        </Fragment>
      ))}
    </main>
  );
};

export default Faq;
```

I also think my code is not good to solve simple problem like this accordion.   I would appreciate if someone tell me where is the problem in my code.

Thanks

Comment: Apart from your problem, I think you don't need `isOpen` state at all, just `selectedId` state is enough. When `selectedId` is `null` actually the accordion is closed and when it's not `null`, the corresponding item is open.

Comment: In handleClick, you should not expect `setSelectedId(id)` to change the value of `selectedId` used in the following if.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [issues/15486#issuecomment-873516817](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15486#issuecomment-873516817), you should use `e.preventDefault()` in the click event handler of `<details/>`

Besides, you don't need the `isOpen` state. The `selectedId` state is enough.

e.g.

```
import { Fragment, useState } from 'react';

const Faq = ({ questionsObj }) => {
  const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState(null);
  function handleClick(e, question) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (selectedId !== question.id) {
      setSelectedId(question.id);
    }
  }

  return (
    <main>
      {questionsObj.map((question, index) => (
        <Fragment key={question.id}>
          <details
            onClick={(e) => handleClick(e, question)}
            open={selectedId === question.id}
          >
            <summary>
              <span>{question.question}</span>
              <span>{selectedId === question.id ? '-' : '+'}</span>
            </summary>

            <p>{question.answer}</p>
          </details>
          {index !== questionsObj.length - 1 ? <hr /> : null}
        </Fragment>
      ))}
    </main>
  );
};

export default Faq;
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-zqqn2t?file=src%2Ffaq.tsx)

Comment: Thanks Lin.  Your answer solved the problem.  I just added below code so we toggle off the question when we click on it.  Your code toggle question when we click on another question only. `else {
      setSelectedId(null);
    }`
Here is A [live website](https://faq-accordion-mainn.netlify.app/)

Answer (score 0):

`useState` works `async`, so when you click first time `isOpen` will be false because condition will match id(latest value) with selectedId(old value). so it will work on second click.

Solution is As above ans you don't need 2 diff state. `selectedId` is enough for you, but clear id on second click so it can close as like as your code.

```
import { Fragment, useState } from "react";
import minus from "./icon-minus.svg";
import plus from "./icon-plus.svg";

const Faq = ({ questionsObj }) => {

    const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState();

    function handleClick(id) {
        if (selectedId !== id) {
            setSelectedId(id);
        } else {
            setSelectedId('');
        }
    }

    return (
        <main>
            {
                questionsObj.map((question, index) =>
                    <Fragment key={question.id}>
                        <details onClick={() => { handleClick(question.id) }} open={selectedId === question.id}>
                            <summary>
                                <span>{question.question}</span>
                                <img src={selectedId === question.id ? `${minus}` : `${plus}`} alt="" />
                            </summary>
                            <p className="animate__animated animate__flipInX">{question.answer}</p>
                        </details>
                        {index !== questionsObj.length - 1 ? <hr /> : null}
                    </Fragment>
                )
            }
        </main>
    );
};

export default Faq;
```

Comment: In your case event handler is not a problem, event handle will be needed when you will use form tag.

Comment: Hello Bharat, I did copy/paste your solution and it did not work.  The first click when page loads does not toggle on the question despite the selectedId set to question id.  I guess it does not work for the same reason of the problem in my initial code. ( Async nature of useState)